# Folder with custom files (json, txt) in dart project (Aqueduct)

Tags: dart, yaml, webstorm, aqueduct

I create dart web server on aqueduct. And i want add into project my custom file (f.e. in json format) and read in dart code. In which folder i can put my own custom non-dart files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put your non-Dart files into any directory, even alongside your Dart files. Just put them wherever makes most sense to you for your project.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have already understood, with library 'resource'.